# Changing IOPub data rate in Jupyterlab

Tags: python-3.x

I will preface this by saying that I am very new to python and PostgreSQL, and programming in general. I am currently working on querying data from a PostgreSQL server and storing the data in a python program running on Jupyterlab 0.32.1. Up until this point, I have had no problems with querying this data, but now I am receiving an error.

```
import psycopg2 as p 
ryandata= p.connect(dbname="agent_rating")
rcurr = ryandata.cursor()
rcurr.execute("SELECT ordlog_id FROM eta")
data = rcurr.fetchall()

mylist= []
for i in range(len(data)):
     orderid = data[i]
     mylist.append(orderid)
print (mylist)
```

**IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable**

**`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)**

Can anyone help fix this?

Comment: I think you forgot to post the error. Also, make sure to post the code that is giving this error so we can see what could be causing it.

Comment: Oops, also new to this site. I've edited my original question.